# Django: Unable to run async requests.get on google. Exception Response can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python-3.x, django, async-await, python-requests

I am unable to understand how async works. I send simple get requests to google with a proxy to check the validity of proxy in a async method. I get the error:

```
'''object Response can't be used in 'await' expression'''
```

Method to get proxies. Code for getting the list of proxies is copied from a tutorial:

```
def get_proxies(self, number_of_proxies=10):
    """Returns max 10 free https proxies by scraping 
    free-proxy website.
    @arg number_of_proxies to be returned"""
    try:
        if number_of_proxies > 10: number_of_proxies = 10
        url = 'https://abc-list.net/'
        response = requests.get(url)
        response_text = response.text
        parser = fromstring(response_text)
        proxies = set()
        for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr'):
            if len(proxies) >= number_of_proxies:
                break
            if i.xpath('.//td[7][contains(text(),"yes")]'):
                #Grabbing IP and corresponding PORT
                proxy = ":".join([i.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')[0], i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0]])
                proxies.add(proxy)
        return proxies
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception while abc list from url: ', e)
        return None
```

Method to check the validity of proxy:

```
async def is_valid_proxy(self, proxy):
    """Check the validity of a proxy by sending 
    get request to google using the given proxy."""
    try:
        response = await requests.get("http://8.8.4.4", proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy}, timeout=10)
        if await response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            print('got a valid proxy')
            return True
    except Exception as e:
        print('Invalid proxy. Exception: ', e)
        return False
```

Method to get the valid proxies:

```
async def get_valid_proxies(self, number_of_proxies=10):
    proxies = self.get_proxies(number_of_proxies)
    print(len(proxies), proxies)
    valid_proxies = []
    valid_proxies = await asyncio.gather(*[proxy for proxy in proxies if await self.is_valid_proxy(proxy)])
    return valid_proxies
```

And a call to the above method:

```
proxies = asyncio.run(get_valid_proxies())
```

Now the best solution for me will be to check the validity of a proxy in `def get_proxies(self, number_of_proxies=10):` before adding it to the proxies list. But have no clue how to achieve that in async way. Therefore, I tried to do a workaround but that is also not working. The method works without async but I call this method many times and it is very slow, therefore would like to make it async.
Thank you

Now after changing the above code by using aiohttp it still throws an exception and doesn't look like async as the requests seem to be sent after one finishes as its very slow same as before.

New is_valid_proxy:

```
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        session.proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy}
        async with session.get('http://8.8.4.4', 
        timeout=10) as response:
            status_code = await response.status_code
    # response = await requests.get("https://www.google.com/", proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy}, timeout=10)
    # if await response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            if status_code == requests.codes.ok:
                print('got a valid proxy')
                return True
except Exception as e:
    print('Invalid proxy. Exception: ', e)
    return False
```

Won't even display the error or exception. Here is the message:

```
Invalid proxy. Exception:
```

Comment: requests is not async compatible. You'll need to use a library like httpx or aiohttp to make async requests: https://www.python-httpx.org/async/
https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that. I need only the response.status_code not the text or content from response. I will read more about aiohttp session to see if they can be used with different proxies and headers. As I send request to one website 100*times so want to use request with different header and proxy. And I don't have much knowledge but in my scenario it won't be wise to keep the session I guess?